# .htaccess 301 redirect and remove .html combined

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect all .html files form stripelatice_ui folder to root and remove .html extention

```
localhost:8089/stripelatice_ui/home.html
```

to

```
localhost:8089/home
```

i have tried using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [QSA,NC,L]


RewriteRule ^stripelatice_ui/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

but it is giving be error saying that the page has redirection loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /stripelatice_ui/

# To externally redirect /stripelatice_ui/file.html to /file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /stripelatice_ui/(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: actually i want to redirect /stripelatice_ui/file.html to /file

Comment: first rule is working but neither /file.html nor /file is serverd. it is giving not found error

Comment: Added in my answer, didn't know your .htaccess was in `stripelatice_ui` directory.